# Getting the line number for each word in a file

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to get all line numbers to a word with this code

```
orddic=dict()
counter=0


with open(path, "r") as f:
    with open(path2, 'w') as g:
        f.readline()
        for rowf in f:
            counter+=1
            rowf=rowf.strip()
            rowf=rowf.replace("\t", "")
            rowf=rowf.split(" ")
            for x in rowf:
                if x not in orddic:
                    orddic[x]=1
                    x=list().append(counter)
                if x in orddic:
                    orddic[x]+=1
                    list(x).append(counter)
                for m in orddic:
                    print (f"{m} ---------Antall: {orddic[m]} ---------Linje:{list(m)}\n")
```

but it slices my word and says it is a list

Answer (score 0):

I am not really sure what you were trying to do from the code you posted, but a standard way to read a file and get each line number is like so:

```py
with open("my_file.txt", "r") as f:
    for index, line in enumerate(f):
        print(f"#{index}: {line}")
```

This would print each line in your file like so:

```
#0: first line
#1: second line
...
```

Explanation:
You can iterate an open file object to get the current line.
The `enumerate` function returns the index of the value in the iterated value, and its value.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: I tried to save each line number to a list for that word, and then print the word and each line the words is in. example: "Hello" occuring 4 times in line numbers(4, 5, 6)